# Entity Framework can't create database (Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)")

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

VS 2017

ASP.NET MVC 5 Empty Project

Entity Framework 6

SQL Server Express 2017

Project is located in c:\users\user\source\repos\project

Code First

Connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="IdentityDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\IdentityDb2.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
```

then changed to:

```
<add name="IdentityDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Public\Documents\IdentityDb2.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
```

In first case getting error

> Directory lookup for the file
>   "C:\Users\user\source\repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\IdentityDb2.mdf"
>   failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.). CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.

on line

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

In second case

> Unable to open the physical file
>   "C:\Users\Public\Documents\IdentityDb2.mdf". Operating system error 5:
>   "5(Access is denied.)". An attempt to attach an auto-named database
>   for file C:\Users\Public\Documents\IdentityDb2.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.

on same line

Installation of last cumulative update didn't help

Comment: Have you tried to open the properties of database (from the explorer) and set read-write to role 'EVERYONE'?

Comment: i have no database file
i tried it with App_Data folder, didn't help.
and when i manually create database, it has no read-only checked

Comment: Try running your Visual Studio instance as Administrator => open project => run => fixed?

Comment: Tried. Didn't help

Comment: If you don't have database file, how can you expect of application to read a file?

Comment: In both connection strings you are attachhing database from directory and you say you don't have database file. I am confused.

Comment: i wrote "and when i manually create database, it has no read-only checked"

Comment: I have the save problem.   How do you solve it?